# Is inverse of Reciprocal Rule (of differentiation) true: if $f'(a)$ doesn't exist, then $\left(\frac 1 f \right)'(a)$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

(Let $f$ be a real-valued function of a real variable. Assume $f(a)\neq 0$. Define $\frac 1 f:\text{Domain } f \setminus \{x:f(x)=0\}\to \mathbb R $ by $\left(\frac 1 f \right)(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$.)

The Reciprocal Rule (of differentiation) says that if $f'(a)$ exists, then $\left(\frac 1 f \right)'(a)$ exists (with $\left(\frac 1 f \right)'(a)=-\frac{f'(a)}{\left(f(a)\right)^2})$.

Can we say that if $f'(a)$ doesn't exist, then $\left(\frac 1 f \right)'(a)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: @DARK: "$f(x)=\frac 1 x$ at $x=0$" But then $\left(\frac 1 f \right)(0)$ doesn't exist and so $\left(\frac 1 f\right)'(0)$  doesn't exist

Comment: Isn't it the case that if we let $g = 1/f$ then the inverse becomes the contrapositive? Or do your assumptions not carry over?

Comment: @BrianTung: Please see my comments to Ted Shifrin's answer below

Comment: @BrianTung: I gave a counterexample below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Counterexample:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the Dirichlet function, i.e.

$$
f\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}
1, & \text{ if }x\in\mathbb{Q},\\
0, & \text{ if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$

Now, the reciprocal function is $\frac{1}{f}:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left(x\right)=1$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then $f\left(a\right)=1\neq0$, $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)$
does not exist, but $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)^{\prime}\left(a\right)=1$.

---

The claim is true with the Additional Assumption that $f$ is continuous
on some open interval around $a$. Proof:

We'll prove the contrapositive: Suppose $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)^{\prime}\left(a\right)$
exists. (We'll show $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)$ exists.)

Then $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left(a\right)=\frac{1}{f\left(a\right)}$
exists. So, by Reciprocal Is Non-Zero, $\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left(a\right)\neq0$.

Now, by the Reciprocal Rule, $\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)^{\prime}\left(a\right)$
exists.

Since $\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)^{\prime}\left(a\right)$
exists, $\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)\left(a\right)$ exists,
with $\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)\left(a\right)=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left(a\right)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f\left(a\right)}}=f\left(a\right)$.
So, by Reciprocal Is Non-Zero, $f\left(a\right)\neq0$.

So, by the Additional Assumption, for all $x$ in some open interval
around $a$, we have $f\left(x\right)\neq0$ and hence $f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f\left(x\right)}}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)\left(x\right)}=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)\left(x\right)$.
Thus, $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f}}\right)^{\prime}\left(a\right)$.

Comment: It feels wrong to differentiate $\frac{1}{f}$ when it is defined only at rational numbers… I can’t recall the precise definition of derivative I was taught, but Wikipedia says the function should be defined on an open neighbourhood of the point at which we are differentiating the function.

Comment: @X-Rui: We can define the derivative of a function whose domain is $\mathbb Q$: See e.g. [We can define the derivative of a function whose domain is a subset of rational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505310) [About the derivative of a function defined on rational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784875)

Comment: First post seems to be merely suggesting the possibility of a looser definition and the second one gives good reason not to define derivative only on $\mathbb{Q}$. The conventional definition is still to define derivative only when the function is defined on an open interval, based on my research. See Definition 2.2.1 at https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~CLP/CLP1/clp_1_dc/sec_def_deriv.html

Comment: @X-Rui: In the first post, the selected answer states, "There's no reason that a derivative couldn't be defined on such a set like $\mathbb Q$ ... it [the definition of the derivative] works fine on any dense subset of $\mathbb R$, like $\mathbb Q$." I think it's pretty clear to me, but if you disagree, you might consider posting a question of your own.

Comment: @X-Rui: In the second post, the selected answer considers a function $g:\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R $ and states, "That function has derivative $0$ everywhere".

Comment: @X-Rui: Often, in introductory texts (such as the one you linked to), to keep things simple, the derivative is only defined at a point in an open interval. But more generally, the only requirement is that the point be a limit point of the function's domain: See e.g. [Tao, *Analysis I*](https://books.google.com/books?id=x7avEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA217).

Comment: Re the Tao Analysis comment, that’s very interesting to me. Nearly all of entry level textbooks I found just don’t mention the issue of domain altogether. I certainly can’t argue against Tao, but I still can’t shake the iffy feeling. I’ll probably post a question as you suggested now having seen Tao’s definition. By the way here’s a real analysis notes from MIT I found and it also defines derivative only on intervals: Definition 198 on Page 60 from https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_lec_full2.pdf

Comment: @X-Rui: See [Why define derivative for a function defined on an interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530227)

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f=1/(1/f)$. Thus, if $1/f$ is differentiable, so then is $f$.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused: I think initially you gave a counterexample (so that your answer was "no"). But now your answer is "yes"?

Comment: Also, I don't think $f=1/(1/f)$ is true. Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=x$. Then $1/(1/f)$ has domain $\mathbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, so that $f\neq 1/(1/f)$. (I think this little detail can be overcome but it was one of the details I was stuck at)

Comment: You already restricted the domain to eliminate zeroes of $f$. (After I entered the counterexample, I realized I had been wrong.)

Comment: I think the argument is this: Suppose $(1/f)'(a)$ exists. Then by the Reciprocal Rule, $(1/(1/f))'(a)$ exists. Now, since $f=1/(1/f)$ (1), $f'(a)=(1/(1/f))'(a)$ (2) and so $f'(a)$ exists. // My doubt is at (1) and (2). We have in fact $f\neq 1/(1/f)$, so that (2) is not obvious. (I think it can be shown but will take a bit more work.)

Comment: I gave a counterexample below

Comment: @user182601 I do not accept the premise of your counterexample. I was assume we were working in the usual open interval context of the definition of the derivative, not in an esoteric context.